# Weighted adjacency list in Python from a graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, adjacency-list, osmnx

I want to create a weighted adjacency list (with weight=length) in Python from a graph that I downloaded.

Now, I struggle with creating such a list
of the following form:

```
adjacency_list = { 'A': [('C', 8)],
'B': [(('A', 5), ('C', 1)], 'C': [('B', 12)]}
```

It is a directed `Multigraph`.
Please help :)

PS; I tried using `adj_list = nx.to_dict_of_dicts(G, edge_data='length')`, but instead of the actual length it just writes "length" every time.

Comment: looks like homework

Comment: It is a part of a bigger project. This part I got stuck on.

Comment: I want to try out an algorithm, but in my case it needs this form. I work using networkx and osmnx.